# Convert one file into ten by splitting the data

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a file that has > 10 rows. I want to create 9 files that each contains equal number or rows, with the 10th file containing that equal number plus any left over.

I currently get the data from the main file by the following:

```
Dim sData As String

Using sr As New StreamReader(vsFilePath)
    sData = sr.ReadToEnd
End Using

Dim oDataList As New List(Of String)
oDataList.AddRange(sData.Split(Convert.ToChar(ControlChars.Lf)))
```

How can I take oDataList and parse it into 10 files without having to loop through each file and oDataList to write line by line?

Is there a better way them what I am currently doing?

Comment: Little note: `ControlChars.Lf` is a `Char`, and needs no conversion to a `Char`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of the lines is not important, you can do the following to separate the content in 10 equal portions, otherwise, a double loop through the data (one for counting and storing the lines, the other for writing them) is probably necessary.

```
Dim sData As String
Dim counter As Integer
Dim sw(10) As StreamWriter
For i As Integer = 0 To 9 Step 1
    sw(i) = New StreamWriter("path" + something)
Next

Using sr As New StreamReader("path")
    sData = sr.ReadLine()
    While sData IsNot Nothing
        sw(1 Mod counter).WriteLine(sData)
        counter += 1
        sData = sr.ReadLine
    End While
End Using

'add a finally block for closing the 10 streams
```

Comment: Turns out the order is important. I took your model and modified it to have the same order. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of lines in the original file is a relatively small number, you can read them all into an array in a line of code. From there, producing the 10 output files is a simple operation. Here is one such method.

```
Dim path As String = "C:\Temp\test\input.txt"
Dim outputPath As String = "C:\Temp\test\output{0}.txt"

Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(path)

Dim files As Integer = 10
Dim linesPerFile As Integer = lines.Length \ 10
Dim currentLine As Integer = 0

For i As Integer = 0 To files - 1
   Dim iterations As Integer = linesPerFile
   If i = files - 1 Then
       iterations = lines.Length - currentLine
   End If

   Using writer As New StreamWriter(String.Format(outputPath, i))
       For j As Integer = 0 To iterations - 1
            writer.WriteLine(lines(currentLine))
            currentLine += 1
       Next
   End Using
Next
```

...

```
string path = @"C:\Temp\test\input.txt";
string outputPath = @"C:\Temp\test\output{0}.txt";

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

int files = 10;
int linesPerFile = lines.Length / 10;
int currentLine = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < files; ++i)
{
    int iterations = linesPerFile;
    if (i == files - 1)
    {
        iterations = lines.Length - currentLine;
    }

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(string.Format(outputPath, i)))
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < iterations; j++)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(lines[currentLine++]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Open your 10 output files.
- Iterate through every line in the input file doing the following:

  - Split the line up its row elements, then slice them appropriately
  - For every slice, write it to the appropriate file

Violà. You only need to iterate through oDataList once.

Comment: Isn't the row and a line the same?